# SSIS Package Logging in 32-bit vs 64-bit or debug?

Tags: sql-server, logging, ssis

I have a SSIS package where I have set up Package logging on

OnError
OnInformation
OnPre-Execute
OnPostExecute
OnBufferSizeTuning

when I execute this package on the (64-bit) server in VS it will write all the information including things like how many rows are processed from a file and "Pre-Execute phase beginning", however if I execute the package from a file store from a SQL Server Agent job on the same server the package only writes one line "Processing of file  has started".

I looked around but haven't been able to find anything about package logging being different in debug vs a job or 32-bit vs 64-bit.  It is the exact same package - any ideas WHY the package logging would be different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are confusing the two different log options.

You can establish event logging within your SSIS package and direct that output to a table, file, event log, etc.

Short of writing your own utility to run SSIS packages, [dtexec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162810%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) is the thing that translates an SSIS's packages XML into actual commands. dtexec listens for various events and pipes that output to the screen in BIDS/SSDT/VS or logs it in the job step history window. The default for the Visual Studio run differs from the command line or SQL Agent invocation.

The parameters you are looking to set are either `/Cons` ConsoleLog or `/Rep` ReportLog. Most likely ReportLog.

The default execution from SQL Agent is going to be something like `/REPORTING E` That's only going to generate your Errors (as per BOL) logged. You can either strip that from the agent job which then defaults as specified

> If the /Reporting option is not specified then the default level is E
>   (errors), W (warnings), and P (progress).

or explicitly provide your desired reporting events.

In your SQL Agent job step, it probably looks something like this at the end. The beginning is different because that points to a package on the file system and yours will be in MSDB.

[image]

Click the "Edit the command line manually" option and then make /REPORTING bend to your will

Comment: And 32 vs 64 bit has no bearing on the logging. Just determines which dtexec.exe is used

Comment: Thanks for the link to that article.  Looks like setting /Reporting V (verbose) is exactly what I was looking for.